# how to call a another layout file inside a styles in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-theme

i custom the Theme in android Widget.TabWidget android:tablayout
and overide the style of tabwidget in my ownway not using `@android` because
i want to custom my style of API 10 below same like API11+

```
<resources>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme">

        <!-- Window -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/MyTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <!-- TabWidget -->
    <style name="MyTabWidget" parent="android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTabWidgetTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center|center</item>
        <item name="android:tabLayout"> HOW TO CALL api_1_10_indicator.xml LAYOUT FROM MY RES LAYOUT </item>
    </style>

    <!-- TabWidget TextAppearance -->
    <style name="MyTabWidgetTextAppearance" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/select_tabwidget_text_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

my res/layout/api_1_10_indicator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="-3dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-3dip"
    android:background="@color/api_1_10_tab_indicator">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

if i use `<item name="android:tablayout">@layout/api_1_10_indicator</item>`
its not working icant call my own tablayout for the tabwidget that i custom.
HOW TO DO IT?

Comment: My understanding is that styles are for styles, not layouts.  If you want custom attributes, search for `attr.xml`

Comment: this <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator</item> is from android framework and i go to that layout and its a layout from android framework, i tot i can also create a layout and make it overide the @android:layout_indicator. So how can i overide the <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator</item> if i dont use a layout? because its need a layout, how? can you give me hints more